# Get source JARs from Maven repository

Tags: java, maven, mvn-repo

Does anyone have any idea if you can find source JARs on Maven repositories?

Answer (score 843, accepted):

> ## Maven Micro-Tip: Get sources and Javadocs
>
> When you're using Maven in an IDE you often find the need for your IDE to resolve source code and Javadocs for your library dependencies.  There's an easy way to accomplish that goal.
>
> ```
> mvn dependency:sources
> mvn dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=javadoc
> ```
>
> The first command will attempt to download source code for each of the dependencies in your pom file.
>
> The second command will attempt to download the Javadocs.
>
> Maven is at the mercy of the library packagers here.  So some of them won't have source code packaged and many of them won't have Javadocs.
>
> In case you have a lot of dependencies it might also be a good idea to use
>   inclusions/exclusions to get specific artifacts, the following command
>   will for example only download the sources for the dependency with
>   a specific artifactId:
>
> ```
> mvn dependency:sources -DincludeArtifactIds=guava
> ```

Source: http://tedwise.com/2010/01/27/maven-micro-tip-get-sources-and-javadocs/

Documentation: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/sources-mojo.html

Comment: Where does it put them once they're downloaded?

Comment: It puts them in the same directory as the binary JARs under M2_HOME.

Comment: If you're using eclipse, it may be helpful to also do "mvn eclipse:eclipse" afterwards and then refresh your project in eclipse--saves you from manually attaching sources to each file.

Comment: I can't find the sources and javadocs after they are downloaded. I've checked every directory under M2_HOME

Comment: How about the sources and docs for `javaee-(web-)api`? You have to do something extra to get those, right? But what?

Comment: @Lii it appears that javaee-(web-)api dependencies exclude source by design. That is because they are container-provided interfaces. Practically speaking the source depends on the runtime container chosen. https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-11389

Comment: if you have eclipse and the maven plugin you can accomplish this form the right click menu as well.

Comment: After `mvn dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=javadoc` IntelliJ IDEA automatically notices the javadocs, which is very nice.

Comment: Where `mvn dependency:sources` is shorthand for `mvn dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=sources`.  You equally may use  `mvn dependency:sources -Dclassifier=javadoc`.

Answer (score 96):

Configuring and running the maven-eclipse plugin, (for example from the command line `mvn eclipse:eclipse` )

```
   <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean that sources and docs are downloaded when you run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` if you add this to the POM file?

Comment: @RobAu ,where will the source be downloaded, will it be attached to the project it self or somewhere else?

Comment: It will be downloaded as jar in your `M2_REPO` as a xxxx-yy-sources.jar, at the same location as the normal jar. It will get attached as source code for the xxxx-yy jar in the libraries

Comment: If you a netbeans user, go to menu 'tools', 'options', 'java', so access the 'Execution' level and fill the input 'Global Execution Options' with 'eclipse:eclipse' quoted by @RobAu

Comment: @RobAu Excellent answer. No need to run any command. Just adding this plugin will solve everything. But, why this didn't download **Spring Docs** as that of **Hibernate Docs** ?

Comment: @OO7 It depends on the release procedure of the libraries. They can decide not to package sources or package the source in a non-standard way.

Comment: After mvn eclipse:eclipse Will restart of eclipse will automatically point to these source code ..?

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar you need to add the M2_REPO to eclipse, and then just refresh the project.

Answer (score 38):

If a project creates a jar of the project sources and deploys it to a maven repository, then you'll find it :)

Just FYI, sources artifacts are generally created by the [maven-source-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/). This plugin can bundle the main or test sources of a project into a jar archive and, as explained in [Configuring Source Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/examples/configureplugin.html):

> (...) The generated jar file will be named by the value of the `finalName` plus "-sources" if it is the main sources. Otherwise, it would be `finalName` plus "-test-sources" if it is the test sources.

The additional text was given to describe an artifact ("-sources" or "-test-sources" here) is called a classifier.

To declare a dependency on an artifact that uses a classifier, simply add the `<classifier>` element. For example:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.7.ga</version>
  <classifier>sources</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Note that you generally don't do this, most IDEs provide support to download sources (and/or JavaDoc) from the main artifact without declaring explicitly a dependency on them.

Finally, also note that some repository search engines allow searching for artifacts using the classifier (at least Nexus does with the advanced search). See [this search](http://repository.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;gav~org.hibernate~hibernate~~~sources) for example.

Answer (score 19):

The [maven idea plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-idea-plugin/idea-mojo.html) for IntelliJ Idea allows you to specify whether or not sources and java doc should be resolved and downloaded

```
mvn idea:idea -DdownloadSources=true -DdownloadJavadocs=true
```

Comment: Instead of downloading sources for all dependencies, is it possible to download just for some dependencies by specifying it in pom along with dependency itself, may b via some inner tag in dependency tag or something similar?

Comment: This Plugin is Retired

Comment: But, @kiltek the functionality is now built into the Maven UI in Intellij...

Answer (score 19):

To download any artifact use

```
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=groupId:artifactId:version:packaging:classifier
```

For Groovy sources this would be

```
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.6:jar:sources
```

For Groovy's javadoc you would use

```
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.6:jar:javadoc
```

This puts the given artifact into your local Maven repository, i.e. usually `$HOME/.m2/repository`.

`dependency:sources` just downloads the project dependencies' sources, not the plugins sources nor the sources of dependencies defined inside plugins.

Answer (score 18):

To download some **specific source or javadoc** we need to include the GroupIds - Its a comma separated value as shown below

```
mvn dependency:sources -DincludeGroupIds=com.jcraft,org.testng -Dclassifier=sources
```

Note that the classifier are not comma separated, to download the javadoc we need to run the above command one more time with the classifier as javadoc

```
mvn dependency:sources -DincludeGroupIds=com.jcraft,org.testng -Dclassifier=javadoc
```

Comment: Instead of downloading sources for all dependencies, is it possible to download just for some dependencies by specifying it in pom along with dependency itself, may b via some inner tag in dependency tag or something similar?

Answer (score 12):

you can find info in this related question: [Get source jar files attached to Eclipse for Maven-managed dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310720/get-source-jar-files-attached-to-eclipse-for-maven-managed-dependencies)

if you use the eclipse maven plugin then use 'mvn eclipse:eclipse -DdownloadSources=true'

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. I am using Eclipse Kepler. Since this makes proper references in the **.classpath**. Like the following:

Comment: <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/redis/clients/jedis/2.6.0/jedis-2.6.0.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/redis/clients/jedis/2.6.0/jedis-2.6.0-sources.jar">

Comment: When I followed @ RobAu answer only *Hibernate Docs* are downloaded from repo, not *Spring*. Then I visit the link u have provided & followed @ mrembisz & make changes to *Maven preference* & works like a charm. I get *Spring Docs*. @Stefan De Boey Thanks for sharing this. +1.

Answer (score 9):

if you're using eclipse you could also open Preferences > Maven and select Download Artifact Sources, this would let the pom.xml intact and keep your sources or java docs (if selected) just for development right at your machine location ~/.m2

Answer (score 8):

**In Eclipse**

1. Right click on the `pom.xml`
2. Select `Run As` -> `Maven generate-sources`
   it will generate the source by default in .m2 folder

**Pre-Requisite:**

Maven should be configured with Eclipse.

Comment: Answers a different question.  This question is about downloading source JARs not generating them.

Answer (score 5):

In eclipse - click on the project then:

[image].

Comment: I unchecked 'download artifact sources' at eclipse maven setting, so it only download the jar.  But latter, I tried to use this solution to download source, it failed without any message.  I removed the jar folder in maven local repository and download the jar again, then the source jar downloaded success.  I think this is because maven local repository has have the jar, so I cannot use this method to download the source.

Comment: Similarly when you right click a Maven dependency and select Maven\Download Sources (or Javadoc), you can download only for a single dependency.

Answer (score 4):

You can, if they are uploaded. Generally they are called "frameworkname-version-source(s)"

Answer (score 4):

## NetBeans, Context-Click

In [NetBeans 8](https://netbeans.org/features/index.html) with a Maven-driven project, merely context-click on the jar file list item of the dependency in which you are interested. Choose `Download Sources`. Wait a moment and NetBeans will automatically download and install the source code, if available.

Similarly you can choose `Download Javadoc` to get the doc locally installed. Then you can context-click some code in the editor and choose to see the JavaDoc.

[image: screen shot of context-menu item "Download Sources" being chosen in a NetBeans 8 project driven by Maven]

Answer (score 3):

Based on watching the Maven console in Eclipse (Kepler), sources will be automatically downloaded for a Maven dependency if you attempt to open a class from said Maven dependency  in the editor for which you do not have the sources downloaded already.  This is handy when you don't want to grab source for all of your dependencies, but you don't know which ones you want ahead of time (and you're using Eclipse).

I ended up using [@GabrielRamierez's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12498717/2317829), but will employ [@PascalThivent's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2059802/2317829) going forward.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the **groupId** and **aritifactId**,you can generate download url like this.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

http://central.maven.org/maven2/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/

and you will get a page like this, chose the version you need,just enjoy it!
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have also used the eclipse plugin to get the project into the eclipse workspace.
Since I've worked on a different project I saw that it is possible to work with eclipse but without the maven-eclipse-plugin. That makes it easier to use with different environments and enables the easy use of maven over eclipse. And that without changing the pom.xml-file.

So, I recommend the approach of Gabriel Ramirez.

Answer (score 1):

Maven repositories do provide simple way to download sources jar.

I will explain it using a demonstration for "spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure".

1. Go to maven repository -
   https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure
2. The page lists various versions. Click-on to desired one, let's say, 2.1.6.RELEASE - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/2.1.6.RELEASE
3. The page have link "View All" next to "Files". Click it -
   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/2.1.6.RELEASE/
4. The page lists various files including the one for sources - 
   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/2.1.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE-sources.jar

Otherwise, you can always "git clone" the repo from github, if its there and get the specific code.

As explained by others, you can use "mvn dependency:sources" command the get and generate sources jar for the dependency you are using.

Note: Some dependencies will not have sources.jar, as those contains no source code but a pom file. e.g. [spring-boot-starter-actuator](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/2.1.6.RELEASE/). 
As in this case:

> Starter POMs are a set of convenient dependency descriptors that you can include in your application. You get a one-stop-shop for all the Spring and related technology that you need, without having to hunt through sample code and copy paste loads of dependency descriptors.

Reference: [Intro to Spring Boot Starters](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-starters)

Answer (score 1):

In IntelliJ IDEA you can download artifact sources automatically while importing by switching on Automatically download Sources option:

`Settings` →  `Build, Execution, Deployment` → `Build Tools` → `Maven` → `Importing`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For debugging you can also use a "Java Decompiler" such as: JAD and decompile source on the fly (although the generated source is never the same as the original).  Then install JAD as a plugin in Eclipse or your favorite IDE.

Answer (score 0):

If you want find the source jar file for any of the artifact manually, go to maven repository location for the particular artifact and in Files click on 'view All'. You can find source jar file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Eclipse, I would recommend downloading both the source **and** the Javadocs of third-party libraries.

Right click on project and download both as per the screenshot below.

Downloading Javadocs means that typically you can get contextual help for methods from third-party libraries, with useful description of parameters, etc. This is essential if you don't know the library well. In some cases I have found that Javadocs are available when the source isn't.

[image]