# How to include Hibernate Javadoc in NetBeans?

Tags: hibernate, netbeans, javadoc

In netbeans I was looking for a hibernate javadoc option (the code completion is working properly but I was looking for the description of the functions).

I got one JAR file for Hibernate Javadoc : **hibernate-3.2.2.ga-javadoc.jar** but couldn't find a way to include this and make it work in NetBeans. I included the jar file in the Javadocs option of Java Platform/Library Manager, but that didn't provide any solution. I think there is a Hibernate Javadoc Zip/Folder available which provides the source code/class files and will be appropriate in this occasion but I couldn't get any such resources. Any suggestion?

Comment: If you use Maven, you can add the goal execution on maven directives like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059431/get-source-jars-from-maven-repository

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to sourceforge at http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate3/, download the  3.2.2.ga hibernate bundle and include the javadocs and sources from there.

Comment: Ok, I got the whole bundle but adding the Javadocs folder or the source files from Java Platforms are not showing me any change. Can you tell me how to add the javadocs to Netbeans?

Comment: You want to go to Libraries and then add a new library. In the javadoc section, add /documentation/javadoc.

Comment: Somehow I can't make it work - I added other javadocs the same way and they worked properly. I am getting problem only this time. I downloaded the latest Hibernate version - 3.5.5 (though my netbeans doesn't have the latest). From Tools->Library I created a new library and added "/documentation/javadoc" to its javadoc and added this library to my project classpath - No Change. I even added this javadoc to Netbeans's "Hibernate" library as javadoc but getting the same thing. Do I need to add the source files also? Is the "Project" folder is the main source directory? Did u get javadoc working?

Comment: yeah, I got it working exactly the way I said. You do not have to add the sources, just the hibernate jar. However, you should of course add the compile jar as well as the library.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but you MUST use the hibernate3.jar which comes in the .zip downloaded from sourceforge to NetBeans recognize/bind/accredit/link the JavaDoc with the hibernate3.jar.
In my case the hibernate3 which one came with NetBeans7.0.1 is the same version (3.2.5 ga) than the downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate3/ (I unziped both had the same quantity of folders, files...) but different sizes.