# How to get the source jar using maven

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

Is there a way to get the source jar besides the binary jar by using maven?

Comment: possible duplicate of [get source jars from maven repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059431/get-source-jars-from-maven-repository)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<project>
    ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    ...
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```

This works using Eclipse, otherwise you can do this on the command line:

```
# mvn dependency:sources
# mvn dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=javadoc
```

Comment: # mvn dependency:sources # mvn dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=javadoc works. I want to know what is your first solution mean?

Comment: The first one is if you use Eclipse and you put this into your `pom.xml` file managing repositories, dependencies and plugins.

Answer (score 1):

This might help: [Get source JARs from Maven repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059431/get-source-jars-from-maven-repository)