# Adding Psychopath Xpath2 processor as a dependency in a maven project

Tags: java, maven, xpath, intellij-idea, p2

I want to use Psychopath Xpath processor in a project(IDE :Intellij Idea) which uses Apache maven for building which is not available at maven central repo. Psychopath jar is available [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/webtools/downloads/drops/R3.5.0/R-3.5.0-20130610150119/wtp4x-R-3.5.0-20130610150119.zip) . And also I know the fact that the psychopath XPath2 engine is available through the P2 repositories too. 
What do I have to put in my pom.xml to make Maven downloading the .jar + the java source + the javadoc, and eventually the other dependencies (actually IBM ICU, Xerces, JavaCup).

If its available through p2 repositories how to add it in the pom.xml as a dependency.Some where it was suggested to use tycho and add the dependency from the p2 repository. Still needs a better guidance.
Here "[Get a Hudson build with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7468781/get-a-hudson-build-with-maven) " also this issue was discussed but couldn't get something positive out of it.

Comment: Also discussed on the wtp-dev mailing list: http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/wtp-dev/msg08743.html

Comment: Actually he's pointing out a stackoverflow link to how to add dependency which is available in p2 repository which which I went through yet without a solution. I'm the one who started that particular thread. Thanks anyway. 
If a better explanation can be provided it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Maven to download dependencies directly from P2 repositories. Here's a sample setup for Psychopath:

```
<project>
 ...

 <repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>kepler</id>
   <layout>p2</layout>
   <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/201306260900</url>
  </repository>
 </repositories>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>osgi.bundle</groupId>
   <artifactId>org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.100.v201211261519</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>osgi.bundle</groupId>
   <artifactId>java_cup.runtime</artifactId>
   <version>0.10.0.v201005080400</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <build>
  <extensions>
   <extension>
    <groupId>com.github.veithen.cosmos</groupId>
    <artifactId>p2-maven-connector</artifactId>
    <version>0.3</version>
   </extension>
  </extensions>
 </build>
</project>
```