# How to resolve the project javadoc dependencies from the repository by maven commnad-line tool

Tags: maven

Generally speaking, there are three types of package, `*.jar` , `*-sources.jar` and `*-javadoc.jar`,  for each artifact in remote maven repository,  but `mvn` only resolves the `jar` dependencis while compiling the source code.

Could someone tell me how to resolve `*-sources.jar` and `*-javadoc.jar` from remote  repository by `mvn`.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, the others are not dependencies, so there is nothing to "resolve".

If you want to *retrieve* that jar, you can just download `[repo-url]/[groupId]/[artifactId]/[version]/[artifactId]-[version]-sources.jar` ... most repositories can be navigated through the directory structure, so you should be able to find it simply.

You can also try

```
mvn dependency:get groupId:artifactId:version:jar:sources -Dtransitive=false
```

Answer (score 0):

`mvn dependency:sources` can download the source attachments  from remote maven repository if exists. See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html.

But how to get the javadoc?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the question on how to get the javadoc was answered on a related thread here: 
[Get source JARs from Maven repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059431/get-source-jars-from-maven-repository)

It's `mvn dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=javadoc`