# Maven - generate archive of every dependency source

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

Is there a way to get an archive containing every dependency source as a separate artifact ?

What i know is that there is a way to download every source jar using the dependency-plugin as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059431/get-source-jars-from-maven-repository). However these files are downloaded to the local repository.

*What i try to achieve is:*

Ship a JAR containing some runnable code. In addition a ZIP archive cotaining the source-code of shipped dependencies inside the JAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to do something similar, except I also needed to filter the included sources to just those produced by teams at my company.  You may use a combination of the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) and the [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to achieve this.

Here's the configuration I use.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
        <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>retrieve-dependency-sources</id>
          <phase>process-sources</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <classifier>sources</classifier>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dep-sources</outputDirectory>
            <type>jar</type>
            <failOnMissingClassifierArtifact>false</failOnMissingClassifierArtifact>
            <prependGroupId>true</prependGroupId>
            <outputAbsoluteArtifactFilename>true</outputAbsoluteArtifactFilename>
            <excludeTransitive>false</excludeTransitive>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>package-dependency-sources</id>
          <phase>prepare-package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <appendAssemblyId>true</appendAssemblyId>
            <attach>true</attach>
            <finalName>${your.app.finalName}</finalName>
            <descriptors>
              <descriptor>src/main/assembly/dep-source-assembly.xml</descriptor>
            </descriptors>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

And here is the assembly descriptor, `dep-source-assembly.xml`, which should be placed in `src/main/assembly`.

```
<assembly
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
  <id>dep-sources</id>  <!-- whatever you'd like the classifier to be -->

  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${project.build.directory}/dep-sources</directory>
      <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
      <!-- Define the includes if you'd like to have sources only for certain 
           packages.  For my use case, I needed to include just source files
           produced elsewhere in my company, not commonly available jars like
           Spring.  -->
      <includes>
        <include>**/com.mycompany.*.jar</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

It sounds like your use case may be a little different than mine, so you might be able to use the assembly plugin's [dependencySet](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_dependencySet) in place of the separate invocation of maven-dependency-plugin and the fileSet.

One other potential gotcha: if you are doing this for a war or ear, you will need to add a dependency on the project's POM to get the complete set of dependencies.  (See [MNG-1991](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-1991).)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>${my.webapp.groupId}</groupId>
  <artifactId>${my.webapp.artifactId}</artifactId>
  <version>${my.webapp.version}</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```