# Finding the dependecy jar which has the required class in maven

Tags: java, maven, github, jar, dependency-management

In an existing project , I have a class which is used to collect **response of an API call**. I know this class comes in as a `maven dependency` , but I what I don't know is  which is the particular **`dependent jar`** , that has it as their are around **20** of them ?

Our code base is in `github` , the search there in it isn't really effective.

Is there an easy way to determine it ?

Comment: If you're using IntelliJ, just ctrl+click a class reference to jump to the metadata, then check the tab or title bar for the full path to the class, which should include the jar name.  Otherwise, I'd just dump the package-qualified class name in Google and see what comes up.

Comment: http://jarfinder.com is your friend.

Comment: Similar what @MikeStrobel described applies for Eclipse: ctrl+Click on the class name, Show In -> Package Explorer and you see the JAR file, which contains the class.

Comment: What IDE are you using, if any?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get source JARs from Maven repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059431/get-source-jars-from-maven-repository)