# Maven get source repository location of dependencies

Tags: git, maven, url

[1] suggest a way to get source jars of dependencies. But is there a way to get the source repository location of the dependency jars.

[1] [Get source JARs from Maven repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059431/get-source-jars-from-maven-repository)

Answer (score 0):

You're able by using the dependency plugin (available in 2.9 and up), similar to what is described in the link you've posted, only a different goal

> **dependency:list-repositories** displays all project dependencies
>   and then lists the repositories used.

As an example, running on spring-mvc-showcase

> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.9:list-repositories

prints the following output

> [INFO] Repositories Used by this build: [INFO]        id:
>   repository.jboss.com
>         url: http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/    layout: default snapshots: [enabled => true, update => always]  releases: [enabled =>
>   true, update => daily]
>
> [INFO]        id: central
>         url: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2    layout: default snapshots: [enabled => false, update => daily]  releases: [enabled => true,
>   update => daily]
>
> [INFO]        id: jvnet-nexus-snapshots
>         url: https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/snapshots    layout: default snapshots: [enabled => true, update => daily] 
>   releases: [enabled => false, update => daily]
>
> [INFO]        id: org.springframework.maven.milestone
>         url: http://repo.spring.io/milestone    layout: default snapshots: [enabled => false, update => daily]  releases: [enabled =>
>   true, update => daily]
>
> [INFO]        id: org.springframework.maven.snapshot
>         url: http://repo.spring.io/snapshot    layout: default snapshots: [enabled => true, update => daily]  releases: [enabled =>
>   false, update => daily]
>
> [INFO]        id: snapshots.jboss.org
>         url: http://snapshots.jboss.org/maven2/    layout: default snapshots: [enabled => true, update => always]  releases: [enabled =>
>   true, update => daily]

Comment: By source repository location I meant the SVN or GIT location.

Comment: ok, still not sure if I should delete the answer, thinking of leaving it for whomever. It answers in parts, as the sources jars fetched via dependency:sources, are (if available) downloaded from the repository where the dependency resides, hence the missunderstanding. You in fact need an official project source location for a dependency, and there is no standard for this, but often available in meta data within pom.xml