# Java http debugging flat-out stops

Tags: java, sockets, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm debugging a simple server-client socket application, and I have problems at the line

```
inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inStream);
```

When stepping over this line of code, the debugger flat-out stops working, hanging up the debugged program. When I tried (force) stepping into it, after seeing the window to accept terms and conditions of a decompiler I've arrived at a step when it says "Source code does not match the bytecode" in the file "Launcher.class"

This is the faulty function: (arguments passed are "localhost" and 8080)

```
 public void connect(String host, int port) throws IOException {
    if (connected) {
        throw new IOException("Already connected.");
    }

    clientSocket = new Socket(host, port);
    outStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
    outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outStream);
    inStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
    inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inStream);
    connected=true;
    System.out.println("Connected to "+host+" over port "+ port);
}
```

Comment: Did you clean the project and rebuild?

Comment: @chb Rebuilding the project doesn't help. I've also tried going over a BufferedInputStream and creating an ObjectInputStream from that, but alas.

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753524/library-source-does-not-match-the-bytecode-for-class Another poster also suggested that it might be an issue with caching in Gradle.