# Android Studio: Library source does not match the bytecode for class

Tags: android-studio

**Please read in full before voting to dupe to [this!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36753524/6122159)**

I've written an Android library and uploaded a test archive to Bintray. The library is successfully pulled down from Bintrary in a clean Android Studio project, and it works correctly. However, when choosing *Go To --> Declaration* for **one specific file** in my library, Android Studio shows the error `Library source does not match the bytecode for class`.

Now yes, I've already seen [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753524/library-source-does-not-match-the-bytecode-for-class/41952613) where the OP seems to have the exact same problem. **However, none of the solutions mentioned on any of the answers worked.**

I have tried:

- Clicking *Show Diff* and choosing *Ignore whitespaces and empty lines*.
- Gradle Clean
- Gradle Rebuild
- Gradle Sync
- Android Studio Invalidate Caches and Restart
- Doing *Build --> Make Project*

The odd thing is, Android Studio doesn't complain about any of the other files.... The only thing I can think of that could possibly be even remotely related is that the problematic class is `abstract`.

Anyone know what might be going on here? I am using Android Studio v3.4.2