# Cannot resolve method 'parse' in 'DockerImageName' when using Testcontainers and gradle in JUnit5

Tags: java, gradle, apache-kafka, testcontainers

The test fails to compile with error `Cannot resolve method 'parse' in 'DockerImageName'`

```
@SpringBootTest
@Testcontainers
public class KafkaContainerTest {
    @ClassRule
    public static KafkaContainer kafka = new KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.2.1"));

    @Test
    public void testUsage() throws Exception {
            kafka.start();
            testKafkaFunctionality(kafka.getBootstrapServers());
    }
//...
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.4.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-validation', version: '2.3.4.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams'
    implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testCompile 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testCompile group: 'io.projectreactor', name: 'reactor-test', version: '3.3.10.RELEASE'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test'
    testImplementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'
    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:testcontainers:1.14.3'
    testImplementation "org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter:1.14.3"
    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:kafka:1.14.3'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

When navigating to `DockerImageName` class in IntelliJ it says `Library source does not match the bytecode for class DockerImageName`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48695949/480632) did not help.

**Update**

This works

```
testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:testcontainers:1.15.0-rc2'
testImplementation "org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter:1.15.0-rc2"
testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:kafka:1.15.0-rc2'
```

Comment: What is `DockerImageName`?  Whatever it is, it apparently doesn't have a `parse()` method, and so your code is syntactically incorrect because you're trying to call such a method on that object.

Comment: It is `import org.testcontainers.utility.DockerImageName;` as suggested in https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/kafka/ and https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/1e597ccd4fa1a7113d3077599e0b13237c1fef51/core/src/main/java/org/testcontainers/utility/DockerImageName.java

Comment: I concur that you are making a correct call there.  It must be that that class isn't defined, or is defined as something else than what you're showing.    What does the `import` statement look like for that class?  You do have one for it at the top of the file, I hope.

Comment: That method was added recently https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/commit/c3f53b3a63e6b0bc800a7f0fbce91ce95a8986b3#diff-44a23d51c0686477fbe698e7066e4f140355e4fdbc5ae973565fe89bf000f53b I think you should try 1.15.0-rc2

Comment: or why not `new DockerImageName(...)`?

Comment: @tgdavies - I think you might have something there.  Usually, when the source and object are out of sync, it is the object that is older.  At least that's the way it usually seems to be for me.

Comment: If you look at the source, all it does is `public static DockerImageName parse(String fullImageName) {
        return new DockerImageName(fullImageName);
    } `(of course that might change in the future, so calling the static method is preferred, but just creating an instance is an acceptable workaround if you don't want to go to the rc.)

Comment: @tgdavies - didn't want to steal points from you or anything...just wanted this question to have a real answer.  I came around to the answer myself, but you were out in front of me.  If you want the credit for this, just copy my answer and paste it as a new one, or create one of your own, and I'll delete mine.

Comment: No worries Steve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The static `parse` method was only added to the `testcontainers` library back in July.  You're using version `1.14.3`, which was released in May.  I expect that if you upgrade the version of the library to a `15.X` (version `1.15.0-rc2` seems to be the latest), I expect your problem will be resolved.

Alternately, you can change your usage of that library to what it was capable of in version `1.14.3`.

UPDATE: I just saw (and finally understood) @tgdavies's suggestion that you can just call the `DockerImageName` object's constructor directly via:

```
return new DockerImageName(fullImageName);
```