# Create an archive with all dependencies sources

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

When I use this command:

```
mvn dependency:sources
```

Maven will attempt to download source code for each of the dependencies in my pom file (cf. [Get source JARs from Maven repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059431/get-source-jars-from-maven-repository)). But these files are downloaded into my local cache `~/.m2`.

Is there a plugin/way to create an archive into target of my project with all dependencies sources ?