# Install scala source without change pom

Tags: scala, maven

I can install java source from command line:

```
mvn source:jar install
```

So how can I install scala source only with command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2430107/187261) applies to your question.

Scala is a dependency of maven project, so you can fetch it by

```
mvn dependency:sources
```

---

To install jar with sources without updating `pom.xml`

```
mvn source:jar install
```

Comment: What I means is generate source jar from my code. Not download from maven

Comment: I've updated the answer. Without changing `pom.xml` you have no way to change how the jar is generated, your only hope is that default configuration is OK