# Maven: How to compile with and without download Artifact Sources|Javadoc through parameters?

Tags: maven, maven-3, m2eclipse, maven-dependency-plugin, maven-compiler-plugin

In Maven for a cloned project (even multi-module) from GitHub if the `mvn compile` command is executed mostly happens the following:

- it downloads all the dependencies declared according in the `pom.xml` file
- it compiles
- it executes the tests

Until here all is OK.

Now in the STS IDE is possible enable/disable the following checkboxes

- Download Artifact Sources
- Download Artifact Javadoc

as follows:

[image]

In the figure I have disabled them to save space in the repository.

1. Assuming that `mvn compile` by default downloads both (pls confirm if that is correct)
2. How I can indicate explicitly through parameters in the command that Maven should download or not each (`Artifact Sources|Javadoc`)? - therefore represent the GUI settings through parameters in the command line

Comment: I don't think this can be done in command line. I guess it is a feature of m2e.

Comment: even if you are correct - `m2e` should create internally or behind the scenes the command for Maven to be executed, right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get source JARs from Maven repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059431/get-source-jars-from-maven-repository)

Comment: In some way, yes, About my question (1) seems the artifacts are not downloaded by default. It is good. (2) I must test the commands proposed.

Comment: Note: `mvn compile` doesn't execute tests, see [Maven Build Lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference). And dependencies are are only downloaded if they aren't in the local Maven repo yet.

Comment: @ManuelJordan Note that m2e is most probably not just running Maven commands. Maven is written in Java and m2e as well. I guess they directly use the Maven libraries to contact Maven repositories.

Comment: @GeroldBroser when I did mention about the "test" term I mean about to test if the commands proposed to indicate explicitly to get the artifacts works or not - sorry for the confusion

Comment: @JFabianMeier I see, I am going to test the proposed solution(s) in the link shared.

Comment: @ManuelJordan Your comment now is more confusing than your third list item is wrong and your first list item is imprecise . :)