# Download Sources Jar From Maven programmatically

Tags: java, maven

I have a very simple requirement like below -

1. I need to write a command line tool which will accept -
   **groupId, artifactId and version**
2. Then it will download the sources JAR file from maven for that dependency
3. For example , if **groupId = log4j**, **artifactId = log4j** and **version = 1.2.9 ,** then it will download **log4j-1.2.9-sources.jar**

I have done below analysis/tried things so far , but I am not getting any luck.
Can anybody please help me ?

1. Using `maven dependency:copy` plugin as below like - `mvn Dclassifier=sources dependency:copy -Dartifact=log4j:log4j:1.2.8`
2. Above command doesn't download source but only artifact JAR (even if Dclassifier=sources is included)

3.Also Tried - `mvn dependency:sources -Dartifact=log4j -DgroupId=log4j -Dversion=1.2.9` . This requires pom.xml in the directory where maven command is executed which is not a feasible option as that will require pom.xml to be generated dynamically.

Please help if anybody has any clue on how to achieve it ?

Comment: Does [using `dependency:get`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36478213/10871900) work for you? `mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=log4j:log4j:1.2.8:jar:sources -Dtransitive=false` See [the docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html)

Comment: What do you need this for? There might be a simple way.

Comment: I second the question of @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen a command line tool already exists for that which is Maven itself ... just simply define the define those artifacts in your pom file ... maybe using https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html apart from that usually you don't need the source code you usuall consume the jar artifacts?

Comment: Did you mean `-Dclassifier=sources` (notice the `-` before the `D`)?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel that will not solve anything because the parameters do simply not exist...

Answer (score 0):

So first based on your given attempt it could **not** work because those given parameters (defined via `mvn Dclassifier=sources dependency:copy -Dartifact=log4j:log4j:1.2.8`) simply do not exist. Please check the documentation for the [goal `copy`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html).

What you can do is setting up a simply pom file which looks like this:

```
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.soebes.so.example.download</groupId>
  <artifactId>example-download</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        .
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.6.1</version>
        </plugin>
        ..
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>${groupId}</groupId>
                  <artifactId>${artifactId}</artifactId>
                  <version>${version}</version>
                  <classifier>sources</classifier>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

By using the above you could now call the command line like this:

```
mvn dependency:copy@copy  -DgroupId=log4j -DartifactId=log4j -Dversion=1.2.9
```

That will download the given artifact and store into the location defined by `<outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>`