# Eclipse doesn't automatically wire sources when debugging on JBoss

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, eclipse-indigo

When I'm debugging in a Maven dependency, which source I've downloaded and I can view in the Eclipse Java perspective, the source doesn't get displayed.

Shouldn't Eclipse wire the sources automatically?

Answer (score 2):

Go to

> Window->Preferences->Maven

and check

> "download artifact sources"

When you debug code, eclipse should automatically download missing sources (at least for me it works in such way).

Comment: It's checked and the sources are there. But Eclipse won't append them in the `Debug` mode.

Answer (score 0):

The question appears to be very similar or a duplicate to another on StackOverflow. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310720/get-source-jar-files-attached-to-eclipse-for-maven-managed-dependencies).

I thought you had to have the m2 plugin for this, but I haven't checked.