# Can I add LOCAL source jars to maven 2 build without installing them so they can be referenced in eclipse?

Tags: maven, jar, maven-2

Note that this is source jars - not compiled jars.

Assuming I have the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.swinglabs</groupId>
    <artifactId>swingx</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.2</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/swingx-0.9.3.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

How do I add my source jars so they can be referenced in eclipse? (I know I can right-click and add to the jar as source - but I wanted a maven import to do this automatically)

Comment: Can you explain the reason why you want to do this? What do you expect that Maven does with these on the build class path? Compile the packaged source files?

Comment: Are you using m2e in Eclipse?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get source jar files attached to Eclipse for Maven-managed dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310720/get-source-jar-files-attached-to-eclipse-for-maven-managed-dependencies)

Comment: This is not a duplicate - it's not about downloading jars - it's about adding local jars in the project because they can't be downloaded.

Comment: I've added to my answer to show how to handle files that are not available in a public repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the [m2e Eclipse plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/), there's an option to download sources for all dependencies:

- Right-click the project
- Maven > Download Sources

If you're not using m2e, you can download the sources from command line using

```
mvn dependency:sources
```

To get them into Eclipse, you can use

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -DdownloadSources=true
```

The easiest way to handle this is through *m2e* though. I strongly recommend to install it, as it will simplify all other Maven handling from within Eclipse.

If the sources are not available in a public repository, you can either

- Upload the sources to your local Maven repository, if you're using something like Nexus, Archiva or Artifactory.
- Install them locally using the Maven Install plugin: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/installing-secondary-artifacts.html The disadvantage is that it will only be visible to yourself in this case.

Out of the two, the first one (local Maven repository/proxy) is recommended.

Comment: But the point is that this is not available in a maven link. It's a local jar I want to add

Comment: I have added to my answer to explain how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Never tried but this should work

```
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

this would also do

```
 mvn -Declipse.downloadSources=true eclipse:eclipse
```

see this http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html#downloadSources

Comment: This is for jars that can't be downloaded - they exist locally in a directory

Comment: oh, I was confused by previous version of your question. So, you do not have `swingx-version-source.jar` in your local repo?