# Best way to addAll items from a Collection of Sets

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, collectors

What is the best, cheapest, performantest way to achive the following:

I do have a `Collection` of Objects `myObject`, which provide a method returning a Set of Integers. I want to add all the items inside the sets into a new set.

```
LinkedList<myObject>  ll = new LinkedList<>();

    //fill the list bla bla

Set<Integer> result = ll.stream()
    .map(f -> f.getTheSet())
    .flatMap(Set::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));

System.out.println(result.toString());
```

is there a better way of getting a resulting set containing all integers from all objects?
I would like to avoid "unpacking the set" with the `flatMap` command. Instead i think about something like `.addAll` or does it in the end not matter, because `.addAll` unpacks anyway?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can collect using `addAll` with a [3-argument `collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-):

```
Set<Integer> result = ll.stream()
        .map(MyObject::getTheSet)
        .collect(HashSet::new, Set::addAll, Set::addAll);
```

`HashSet::new` makes a new container, `Set::addAll` adds each set into the container, 2nd `Set::addAll` merges two containers if this stream were to be run in parallel.

(or use `TreeSet::new` if you specifically want a `TreeSet`)

Comment: works, but can you explain, what acually happens using   `.collect(HashSet::new, Set::addAll, Set::addAll)`?

Comment: I added a brief explanation and a  link to the 3-argument collect javadoc.  I think It explains it better than I can.  See if that makes sense to you

Answer (score 1):

> Instead i think about something like .addAll or does it in the end not matter, because .addAll unpacks anyway?

`TreeSet.addAll()` has an optimized codepath for adding Collections that implement `SortedSet` assuming they have the same sort order.

Caveat: This is an undocumented implementation detail and thus subject to change.

You could easily have found this information yourself simply looking at the JDK source code, which is [included in the src.zip shipped with the JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460189/browse-jdk-source-code-in-eclipse-like-grepcode).

Comment: Interesting addition. Note though this codepath works only when you add to an empty `TreeSet`, so it may be applicable for the first non-empty stream element only.

Comment: @TagirValeev right, but for parallel streams that could still make a difference for all the leaf tasks.