# Trying to debug my eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I am using JDK 1.7 on my eclipse. I am running Maven Build. I have recently tried to debug my application and at first it would take me to a blank page that only gives the option of "edit source look up" after editing the source look up it still does not work. I have also tried cleaning my project( i have done this numerous of times). I have even checked out a new project and redirected my server to the new folder and it still wont let me debug. I Need help as soon as possible

Comment: Is this a webapp or a standalone app? If web, what application server are you running? Are you running it from the IDE or on the side? Are you sure the jpda port is even listening?  Does eclipse say it is connected to the debug port?  Do you have any logging application-side?

Comment: it is a web app, i am running oracle web logic 10.3.6 server. I am running it from the IDE. I am not sure how to check if the jdpa port is listening or what that is to be honest. though i do know that all of the debug configurations have been set and i haven't changed them. Just after updating my code from SVN the debugger stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

Try Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Download artifact sources. After that right click on your project: Maven -> Update project -> OK.

Comment: I don't see a "Download artifact sources" option in the preferences->Maven window.

Comment: Are you using the m2eclipse plugin? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310720/get-source-jar-files-attached-to-eclipse-for-maven-managed-dependencies