# eclipse-luna maven project dependency jar source attachment

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse, eclipse-luna

I tried right click on the dependency jar-->maven download sources, console says sources downloaded, click on a class file  from this jar, opens class file editor with Source not found M2_REPO........jar has no source attachments  (local repo has the -sources.jar file). Only way I can get src is by clicking on the button Attach Source and add the src path. 
I also installed m2eclipse dynamic source lookup plugin.
Eclipse kepler automatically added src attachment if dependency has src jar  file, but in luna its not doing automatically, please advice how  to trouble shoot this.

Comment: did you get anywhere on this? i think i'm experiencing the same issue. maybe a bug?

Comment: No,I am adding src attachment manually.

Comment: as a workaround, i'm using this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/311229/659715