# Download sourcecode/javadoc automatically for Maven projects on Spring Tool Suite

Tags: eclipse, maven

I'm using Spring Tool Suite in my organization for writing Java code. We have a bunch of Maven projects. Whenever I do an F3(Open declaration) on a library's method, the class file opens up and then STS automatically starts downloading the source code and in a few seconds I see the source code in the editor. How does this happen? I've been trying to replicate this on my home machine to no avail. I looked at other similar posts, the usual suggestions are -

- Check Download Source / Download Javadoc in Maven settings
- Update Maven settings file to instruct Maven to download source/javadoc

None of these are done in my project. So, is there any other way to do it? We are using artifactory as remote repository, if that helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310720/get-source-jar-files-attached-to-eclipse-for-maven-managed-dependencies?rq=1