# Steps to Debug Dependancy In Webapp Eclipse/Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, debugging

I have the Maven Web App, where I have to many dependencies. I am trying to create the Remote Debug configuration in eclipse to debug jars when my home page open. As I am aware to to the debugging on java code, how can i do the same with maven dependencies.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can debug libraries from maven the same way you debug your code. Nothing special need to be configured in debugger.

You just need to make sure for the libraries you're going to debug, sources are available in eclipse.

You can either download and specify them [manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122160/is-there-an-easy-way-to-attach-source-in-eclipse), or let maven download sources [automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310720/get-source-jar-files-attached-to-eclipse-for-maven-managed-dependencies) for you.

Comment: Hi, Actually I want to debug the dependency at level 2. In my project, dependency that I am using if drive from other project by using mvn clean install, and that other project having dependencies say "d1". So I want to debug "d1" in my project. Just tell me will that be work?