# Eclipse: How can I attach JavaDoc to multiple JAR files?

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

I am using Eclipse 3.4.1.

I have an external library that consists of a bunch of JAR files, and some HTML JavaDoc.  I know that I can attach the HTML JavaDoc to individual JARs by going to their Properties page, JavaDoc location, and setting it there.

But it would be a pain to do this for each individual JAR.  Is it possible to do them all at once somehow?  The JavaDoc location is the same for them all.

Answer (score 3):

Not really a recommended solution, but you could set it for one of them and then manually edit your project's `.classpath` file, copy the relevant part and paste it into the other elements. Not that much easier than setting it for each one separately, though.

Also, if you have access to the source files, you could use these instead of the Jar files, which will provide the Javadocs.

Comment: Yep, still after 10 years we can't attach one Javadoc to multiple JARs in Eclipse, which is just... annoying. Damn, we cannot even set relative path to javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

I had a related question, on how to efficiently attach JavaDocs for dozens of JAR files from our in-house projects which are in a Maven repository. The solution was to use the Maven JavaDoc Plugin to automatically [build and install JavaDoc and Source artifacts](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/attach-source-javadoc-artifacts.html) for each project. Then in Eclipse I could import all of these resources with one step by right clicking on the project->Maven->Download JavaDoc. Then Shift-F2 does its magic.

That process only works for dependencies which are not in my Eclipse workspace. For each of my Eclipse projects, I still had to configure its JavaDoc location manually, but at least there are fewer of these.

Here's a related topic:
[How to reference javadocs to dependencies in Maven's eclipse plugin when javadoc not attached to dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396/how-to-reference-javadocs-to-dependencies-in-mavens-eclipse-plugin-when-javadoc)