# Download dependency Jar's with with source and Javadoc with Play framework

Tags: eclipse, jar, dependencies, playframework, javadoc

Is it possible to specify sources and/or javadocs to be included in dependency JAR's with the Play Framework?

I want to be able to browse the source and javadocs for 3rd party libraries in Eclipse. The Maven Eclipse plugin can apparently be configured to provide this functionality [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396/how-to-reference-javadocs-to-dependencies-in-mavens-eclipse-plugin-when-javadoc), I'm wondering if Play provides similar facilities as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the Maven plugin? http://www.playframework.org/modules/maven

It explicitly mentions source and javadocs in its description.

> Expected behavior this module:
>
> - Allow declaration dependencies in pom.xml, without putting
>     explicitly unless the transitive dependency does not work (for older
>     version or depending on undesirable big jar file)
> - Able to download all dependencies not provided by Play into lib
>     folder, with src and javadoc
> - Able to download source/javadoc artifiacts to depsrc folder for
>     declared or transitive dependency which is provided by Play, for
>     easier debugging (using command mvn:play-src)

Comment: I was aware of the Maven plugin but it doesn't claim support for Play 1.2 which I'm using. Sounds like I should file a feature request for native support in Play, I'd rather not duplicate core framework functionality.

Comment: The instructions do seem to show how to use the Maven plugin with the play dependencies, which was new in Play 1.2, so it is worth a try. Not all plugins have been updated, but still work.