# Source not found - Importing javadoc on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I have set `downloadJavadocs` to true in maven-eclipse-plugin, but even after re-generating the eclipse project javadocs doesn't seem to show up.

This is my code as follows:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-eclipse-plugin.version}</version>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>configure-workspace</goal>
                <goal>clean</goal>
                <goal>eclipse</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <workspace>${env.USERPROFILE}/workspace</workspace>
        <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
        <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
        <projectnatures>
            <projectnature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</projectnature>
        </projectnatures>
        <buildcommands>
            <buildcommand>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</buildcommand>
        </buildcommands>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <wtpmanifest>true</wtpmanifest>
        <wtpapplicationxml>true</wtpapplicationxml>
        <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When i try to view the javadocs, it shows that `Source not found` error. I'm unable to understand while causing this errors. How do i fix it?

Comment: Would this help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396/how-to-reference-javadocs-to-dependencies-in-mavens-eclipse-plugin-when-javadoc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the **settings.xml** configuration file for Maven.

From inside Eclipse go to *Preferences => Maven => User Settings*.

It might be the case that instead of using the public repositories, which contain the source, you have some other repositories specified (maybe company-wide repos) that contain only the jars and not the source.