# How to download sources and javadoc artifacts with Maven Eclipse plugin from other repository?

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, javadoc

I have spring framework dependencies in my Maven project. I want to attach the Javadoc for spring framework dependencies.

I added to `pom.xml` following lines

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>springsource-repo</id>
        <name>SpringSource Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.springsource.org/release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
<plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
            <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
            <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

I have installed m2eclipse and I also checked option `Download Artifact Sources/Javadoc` in settings.

When I run `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, it doesn't show any warnings. But javadoc `.jar` files aren't downloaded.

Comment: The configuration you set should work. But if you first tried without having a repository that provides the artifacts, eclipse plugin will keep a cache of non-available artifacts. Just launch a eclipse:remove-cache to be sure it is not the case here.

Comment: Are you working with m2e in Eclipse? Which Version of Eclipse?

Comment: @Tome Your suggest with option `eclipse:remove-cache` helped me. But there was other issue, javadoc for spring version `3.0.2` wasn't on the repository server. So after removing cache I saw this issue and changed version to `3.2.0` and run eclipse:eclipse again. And it works!

Answer (score 30):

In Eclipse goto **Windows->preferences->Maven** and there you check the box with *download sources* and may be *download javadoc* as well. That should do the trick.

Comment: Try to select a class from Spring Framework. Don't use mvn eclipse:eclipse if you are using m2e.

Comment: When I'm using m2e, are jars downloaded automatically?

Comment: Yes the were. Which Eclipse version do you use?

Answer (score 1):

You can download from this location http://repo.spring.io/libs-release/org/springframework/spring/

Answer (score 0):

With a Maven project, simply run in the command line:

> mvn dependency:sources