# Source Not Found Java

Tags: java, spring

I got the error when i run my spring project it will show the messages which is found in image link.

I downloaded spring jar files 4.1.6 version and configured as a user library.

Kindly help me to get rid of this error so i can continue my project.

Kindly download the screen shot

Waiting for a response.

Thanks.
[Image Link](http://s29.postimg.org/z9b1icdlz/problem.jpg)

Comment: Its not an error..you need to attach the source file to view the content of that jar file

Comment: There is a separate source code ZIP that comes along with the binary release. Search for it in your preferred maven repository and add it as source attachment. Simply click on 'attach source' and choose the sources file that is shown on the left

Answer (score 0):

When you make a jar file from .java files these jar file will contain .class files which represent the code that the java compiler need to run the program.

In eclipse opening the jar file you need the **source code** of the .class file so as you see in the error you need the **attached source**.

So you have to find the source code of jar or download the jar with the source code build it.

I think you can find it on  [Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework)

Also if you want take a look  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993503/how-to-view-the-spring-framework-javadoc-in-eclipse)

Also you can check the **javadoc** of the jar file you have downloaded it has a total presentation of all the classes and methods.

Comment: I think the sources are already there, look at the left oft the screenshot

Comment: What should i download from Githib there are many files in it.

Comment: @Abtisam Ansari what exactly you want to check ? let me know.. As i saw now your project has javadoc inside go and open them if you want to see details about classes and methods.

Comment: Actually i want to run my spring project but it is not running, While debugging it shows an error in "ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("springConfig.xml");" line .  Complete code is in next comment.

Comment: import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
importo rg.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class TestingSpringProject {

 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
  String demo = "";
  ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("springConfig.xml");
  Resturant resturantObj = (Resturant) context.getBean("resturantBean");
  resturantObj.greetMessage();
 }

}