# maven project downloading -sources jar files

Tags: maven

every time I do maven update, it downloads libs ends with -sources. build path shows libs are missing
[image]

[image]

Comment: what does maven say when you update, anything?

Comment: There are two options either Maven is configured accordingly (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/examples/attach-library-sources.html) There is also a doc here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396/how-to-reference-javadocs-to-dependencies-in-mavens-eclipse-plugin-when-javadoc

Answer (score 0):

Based on screenshots attached, it is not Maven, but Eclipse's Maven plugin "M2E"  that downloads sources. Please check `Maven` section in Eclipse preferences. Also, an update may be required, as there were known issues some time ago: See [this github ticket](https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/issues/332) for details.